# Match a string with brackets

Tags: c#, regex

This is a noob question, but my Regex skills in general are rather poor.
I want to match a string according to the following format:

left-bracket left-parenthesis C or R L right-parenthesis any A-Z a-z right-bracket

Thus, a string `[(CL)test]` is correct, while `[blah(ll` is not.

I have this regex pattern:

```
^\\[\\([RC]L\\)[A-Za-z]\\]$
```

But it fails to match the correct string (obviously due to my mistake, but I can't find it).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the quantifier:

```
^\\[\\([RC]L\\)[A-Za-z]*\\]$
                       ^
```

Or

```
^\\[\\([RC]L\\)[A-Za-z]+\\]$
                       ^
```

Otherwise, your regex just tries to match a single `[A-Za-z]`.

And you can use `@` in C# to avoid double escaping:

```
@"^\[\([RC]L\)[A-Za-z]+\]$"
```

Comment: I even understood what I did wrong :). Thanks, will accept when the system lets me.

Answer (score 1):

```
string regex = @"\[\((C|R)L\)[a-zA-Z]+\]"
```

should work for you

Answer (score 1):

add the *

^[([RC]L)[A-Za-z]*]$

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the use of a quantifier after your character class `[]`

```
*      Match 0 or more times
+      Match 1 or more times
```

Also, you can avoid using double escapes `\\` in your regular expression here and either use the `(?i)` modifier or `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` for case-insensitive matching.

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^\[\([rc]l\)[a-z]+\]$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

`@"^\[\([RC]L\)\w+\]\n?$"` should do what you want.